# How to get a discontinuous list according to the values of other list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to give a list of number to a dataframe. The result I want is as below:

```
Unit        Ida
            1      
Parcel 1    2
Parcel 2    2
Parcel 3    2
            3
            4
Parcel 1    5
Parcel 2    5
```

The first code i used is as below:

```
    Address['Ida'] = ''
    Ida = 1
    Address['Ida'][0] = Ida
    for x in range(len(Address)-1):
        if str(Address['Unit'][x+1]) == ('Parcel 1' or ''):
            Ida = Ida + 1
            Address['Ida'][x+1] = Ida
        else:
            Address['Ida'][x+1] = Ida
```

But speed of my code is very very slow. So in pandas, is there any better efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `cumsum` with `shift`

```
((df.Unit=='')|(df.Unit=='Parcel1')).cumsum()
Out[129]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    5
Name: Unit, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Really helps me!!! Thanks, and the speed is so quick! If you have time, could you tell me the reason why it is so quick and why my code is so slow? I am very curious..

Comment: @yuchenhuang this is vectorized function , which means it will not check the row by row , in your for loop you went thru each line

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think it means we'd better to use numpy or pandas function to do something, instead of use python directly.

Comment: @yuchenhuang if you doing a check row by row , for loop is not recommend

Comment: Many thanks! I ask a new question about how to replace my one another for loop, could you help my find a numpy way?